# How to anchor views in Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

I wanna anchor a container between two views like the above image.

Currently, I'm using the following method but it doesn't seem to work in different screen sizes.

```
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: OvalClipComponent(clipHeight),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .60,
            color: Colors.white,
          )
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .25),
        child: Container(
          height: AppConstants.adaptiveScreen.setWidth(400),
          width: AppConstants.adaptiveScreen.setWidth(400),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: AppColors.shadowColor1, blurRadius: 10, offset: Offset(0, 2))],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              border: Border.all(color: AppColors.colorTransparent, width: 3)),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 20,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                ''),
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Still need a bit more info. Your code only show containers but your screenshot shows text and textfields as well. Maybe show us the code which renders the screenshot and  describe which element you want where?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to anchor the profile image view to the bottom and top containers. Can't add the full code bcoz StackOverflow gives me an error.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want it to look like. Maybe add a simple drawing?

Comment: I just want to anchor(overlay) my profile image like in the top image credit card view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217520/discussion-between-er1-and-shehan-madushanka).